# InternalsVisibleTo attribute with signed assemblies in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, signing, strongname

I have a .NET 6 project called `A.dll` that is strongly signed. I also have a test project called `A.Test.dll` that must have access to the internals of `A.dll`. This means `A.Test.dll` must be strongly signed and the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute must be used in `A.dll`. But I am unable to make this work. I use the SDK style project files.

I have set these properties in a common file for both `A.dll` and `A.Test.dll`:

```
<SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
<AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>..\Key.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
```

I can build the two projects and the strong name of the `A.test.dll` project looks like this: `A.Test, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=01234567890abcdef`.

In `A.csproj` I do this:

```
   <ItemGroup>
      <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute">
         <_Parameter1>A.Test</_Parameter1>
      </AssemblyAttribute>
   </ItemGroup>
```

and I get the following error:

```
error CS1726: Friend assembly reference 'A.Test' is invalid. Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their InternalsVisibleTo declarations.
```

I want to add the public key token, and I do it as follows:

```
   <ItemGroup>
      <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute">
         <_Parameter1>A.Test, PublicKeyToken=0123456789abcdef</_Parameter1>
      </AssemblyAttribute>
   </ItemGroup>
```

This results in the following error:

```
error CS1726: Friend assembly reference 'A.Test, PublicKeyToken=0123456789abcdef'
is invalid. Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their InternalsVisibleTo declarations.
```

If I add the entire name, as follows:

```
   <ItemGroup>
      <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute">
         <_Parameter1>A.Test, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0123456789abcdef</_Parameter1>
      </AssemblyAttribute>
   </ItemGroup>
```

then I get the following error:

```
error CS1725: Friend assembly reference 'A.Test, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0123456789abcdef' is invalid. InternalsVisibleTo declarations cannot have a version, culture, public key token, or processor architecture specified.
```

So what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Read the messages carefully. The first says *"must specify a public key"*, not "must specify a public key *token*". You need the full public key.

Comment: The last message says *"cannot have a [...], public key token"*.

Comment:  yep. that was it. I needed the public key not the token. that was kind stupid of me. thanks for the help